# select2 does not work in table with data-toggle=“table”

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, bootstrap-table

I have a table in my project whose first row is input fields.

These input fields have Jquery events such as **keyup** and **keydown**. Also in my first column I make use of  **select2**.

First column:

```
<td class="input-list-produto">@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Produto.DescricaoProduto, new MultiSelectList(Model.Produtos, "CodigoProduto", "DescricaoProduto"), new { @class = "form-control select-multiple" })</td>
```

This is my Java Script code:

```
$("#Produto_DescricaoProduto").select2({});

 $("#Produto_PrecoEmbalagem").keyup(function (e) {
        var key = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode;
        if (key != KisaborUtils.KEY_DOWN_TAB_VALUE) {
            var quantEmb = $("#Produto_QuantidadePorEmbalagem").val();
            var precoEmb = $("#Produto_PrecoEmbalagem").val();

            var precoEmbNorm = KisaborUtils.normalizeDecimalNumber(precoEmb);
            var precoUni = precoEmbNorm / quantEmb;

            var valor = Math.round(precoUni * 100) / 100
            $("#Produto_PrecoUnitario").val(valor);
        }
    });

    $("#Produto_PrecoUnitario").keyup(function (e) {
        var key = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode;
        if (key != KisaborUtils.KEY_DOWN_TAB_VALUE) {
            var quantEmb = $("#Produto_QuantidadePorEmbalagem").val();
            var precoUni = $("#Produto_PrecoUnitario").val();

            var precoUniNorm = KisaborUtils.normalizeDecimalNumber(precoUni);
            var precoEmb = precoUniNorm * quantEmb;

            var valor = Math.round(precoEmb * 100) / 100
            $("#Produto_PrecoEmbalagem").val(valor);
        }
    });
```

My application works perfectly. However during the project I had to change my table to an equal this example:
[enter link description here](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#methods/toggle-fullscreen.html)

Leaving my table in full screen.

But by adding **data-toggle="table"**, I lose all my events from **jquery** and library **Select2**

This is my table:

```
                            <table class="tableProduto"
                               data-toggle="table"
                               data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                               data-height="460"
                               data-show-fullscreen="true">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Produto</th>
                                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                                    <th>Preço embalagem R$</th>
                                    <th>Preço Unitário R$</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="input-list-produto">@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Produto.DescricaoProduto, new MultiSelectList(Model.Produtos, "CodigoProduto", "DescricaoProduto"), new { @class = "form-control select-multiple" })</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Produto.QuantidadePedido, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-grid input-sm", @type = "number", @min = "0", @step = "1", @value = "0" } })</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Produto.PrecoEmbalagem, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-grid input-sm", @type = "text", @min = "0", @value = "0" } })</td>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Produto.PrecoUnitario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-grid input-sm", @type = "text", @min = "0", @value = "0" } })</td>
                                    <td id="salvarItem"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">SALVAR</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

My question is, how can I use my table with **data-toggle="table"**, and not lose my JavaScript events?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$("#Produto_PrecoEmbalagem").keyup(function (e) {
  //whatever...
}
```

with

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#Produto_PrecoEmbalagem', function(e){
  //whatever...
})
```

Read more about event delegation [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

To improve the performance of your page, you want to delegate the events to the smallest possible common parent of all the elements the event applies to and, instead of binding to `'body'`, you should bind to that element.